# What determines the value of a life of a lifeform?

Tags: dharma, life, adharma

Killing a human is a bigger sin than killing a fish, and killing a fish is a bigger sin than killing a tree. This is because a human has a more valuable life than a fish or a tree.
What determines the moral value of a life form, according to Hindu scholars?

For multiple reasons, the karma of its previous lives cannot be relevant to how a life form is treated by humans.

Comment: It is determined by the amount of sins committed by the life form in the previous births .. a tree is a Jiva (life form) which has committed more sins compared to a Jiva which is currently an animal and so on. Basically killing a being which has greater sins is lesser sin compared to killing a being which has relatively less sins.

Comment: @Rickross That sounds problematic. Karma itself will punish evildoers in their next lives, without any need for human intervention. Evildoers who have been reincarnated as plants have already been punished by nature for their sins, so there isn't need for any extra human punishment. So the previous life of a life form is irrelevant for how humans should treat it. It should be based off of other factors.

Comment: Not completely punished .. some remnants of sins will be there otherwise why births as plants or animals? (if sins cleared off completely)

Comment: @Rickross They are punished by being born as a plant or animal. As karma is divine and infallible, it will work regardless of what humans will do.

Comment: How is what humans will do with them is relevant? I am not saying humans need to punish them .. their birth itself is a form of punishment because in those births they are far less privileged

Comment: @Rickross Your idea is problematic. If a person named "A" decided to brutally murder an innocent person named "B", would the sin be diminished, as Person "B" had certainly committed sins in his previous life, causing his brutal murder in his next life? It is no different for other life forms.
So factors other than the karma of an life form must decide the value of it's life.

Comment: @Rickross Your idea would diminish every sin committed on a being.

Comment: @Rickross is wrong in his understanding. Tree doesn't necessarily need to have commited sins.  Rickross answer this question, there were 1 billion humans some years ago, now there are 7+ billion. Where did extra human souls come from?

Comment: Targi, according to my understanding, everything in Hinduism is moksha oriented. So any being who has more probability of attaining moksha or going towards it more is considered more valuable morally. Some insects are more valuable than bacteria, plants and trees even more valuable, holy plants and trees even more valuable, animals more valuable, holy animals(cow, snake, dog, monkey, swan) more valuable, humans more valuable, brahmins(spiritual people) more valuable, saints and sannyasins most valuable.

Comment: @Rickross souls in plants trees etc have nit necessarily been sinful and have comedown from humans, every soul has not been humans. Souls will like atoms, they will enter different life forms starting from simple life, and then progress slowly towards human being.

Comment: @HariKumar I thought only humans could achieve moksha? Wouldn't that mean all non-human beings, including devas, would have the same moral value?

Comment: @TargiKoor correct only Humans can achieve moksha. But other beings are at different distances from being human. For eg: A monkey or a cow iss close to becoming a human, so the probability of it getting Moksha in say next 1000 years is higher than the bacteria. It may take, don't know some extraordinary amount of time. Also if you fall from lesser height the pain is less than if you fall from a more height. You know it's like ludo, if you hit an opponents pawn which is more close to destination rather than the one which is just starting.

Comment: @HariKumar So does that mean devas have a lesser moral value than humans? Also, why would it matter that that a monkey is closer to  achieving a human birth? If I kill a monkey, I'm not going to impact it's chances of getting moksha in the next thousand years.

Comment: @TargiKoor I'm not sure whether Devas have more or less chance of getting moksha. If you kill any animal which is close to getting Moksha then it becomes tough for the animal. Because the bodies which can help you get Moksha are rare to find. It is through a lot of punya that one gets advanced bodies. Taking away that amounts to more sin.

Comment: @TargiKoor because it looses the body. We need to be careful when we are speaking about free will, karma and determinism. Because if we are not careful we will arrive at absurd results. Why animals, even humans don't have free will according to hinduism. So why should we not kill humans?? Now if we kill some human, he got killed because he had negative karma, if not he couldn't be harmed. So killing anyone you should not get sin. So why shouldn't we kill humans?? Whatever answer you give applies proportionally to animals as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138951/discussion-between-hari-kumar-and-targi-koor).

Comment: @TargiKoor I didn't mean to use the word "free will". I was actually talking about how animals cannot make rational, moral choices.